# Getting errors in console in Nextjs while using images from Unsplash

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

I am using Unsplash images in my Nextjs App. Images are loaded and showing in the app but I am getting these errors and warnings. The way I am using images I just copy the image address from Unsplash and paste the URL in the `src` attribute.

Here is the next.config.js file:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  distDir: "build",
  images: {
    domains: ["images.unsplash.com", "cdn.pixabay.com", "images.pexel.com"],
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

**Console error:**

[image]

**Network Tab error:**

[image]

Note: I have also edited the next.config.js file.

Comment: Could you show the edited file?

Comment: I added the config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewing a photo on Unsplash shows a URL of the format `https://unsplash.com/photos/{id}`.

Update your next.config.js to use the domain `source.unsplash.com` instead of `images.unsplash.com`, and then use `http://source.unsplash.com/{id}` in your `src` attribute. The image should then render as expected.